# Display an applet in a webpage using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, applet, html

I have very little experience with HTML and applets. I have tried several of the things I found online, but am unable to make my Java applet run in a web browser (it functions in eclipse).

I have put the HTML file in the same folder as all of my Java class files for the applet. I am currently using Safari, but would like the applet to work in most any popular browser.

How can I display a java applet on a webpage using HTML/JavaScript?  Can anyone offer any tips/advice?

Below is my attempted HTML code.

#### Attempt 1:

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Pendulum Applet</Title>
</Head>
<Body>
<br>
<br>
<embed code="PendulumApplet.class"
  width="200" height="200"
  type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5.0"
  pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/download.html"/></embed>
</Body>
</Html>
```

#### Attempt 2:

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Pendulum Applet</Title>
</Head>

<Body>
<br>
<br>
<OBJECT 
  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
  width="200" height="200">
  <PARAM name="code" value="Applet1.class">
</OBJECT>
</Body>
</Html>
```

Comment: 1) It would probably be both a better experience for the user, and easier, to deploy a `JFrame` from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). 2) The `.class` extension is tolerated, but not correct.  3) HTML element names should be all lower case (e.g. `<html>` as opposed to `<Html>`)  4) Is it `PendulumApplet.class` or `Applet1.class`? 5) What output do you see in the Java console?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
 <APPLET CODE=AppletSubclass.class WIDTH=anInt HEIGHT=anInt>
 </APPLET>
```

OR

```
 <object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.class"></object>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763925/uploading-a-java-applet-into-a-webpage too....

Comment: check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html too

Answer (score 1):

Use [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) to write the applet element.  The script is supported by Oracle, and will:

1. Check the user has the minimum required Java, prompting them to install if not, before..
2. Writing the `object`/`embed` or `applet` element as is best known for that browser.

### Other notes:

1. Is it `PendulumApplet.class` or `Applet1.class`? It is hard enough to debug problems on international forums without introducing doubt about the name of the applet class.
2. The `.class` extension in the `code` attribute is tolerated, but not correct.  The value should be a string representing the Fully Qualified Name of the class.  E.G. `javax.swing.JApplet` as opposed to `javax.swing.JApplet.class`.
3. HTML element names should be all lower case (e.g. `<html>` as opposed to `<Html>`)
4. What output do you see in the Java console?  When debugging applets in a browser, it is vital ensure the Java Control Panel is configured to pop open the console on discovering an applet (or JWS app.).

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not done so myself, my Java textbook provides this outline for an embed:

`<applet
    code = "ClassName.class"
    width = 250
    height = 50
    [archive = archivefile]
    [vspace = vertical_margin]
    [hspace = horz_margin]
    [algin = applet_alignment]
    [alt = alt_text]
>
</applet>`

(Optional parameters in brackets)

Comment: I tried what you said with the object, but when I open the webpage it says Missing Plugin and when I click that, it says there is content that cannot be displayed because its type is unspecified. Any help? (Thanks for your previous post)

Comment: I don't know...  Maybe you don't have the Java plugin installed for your browser?  Can you see the animated applet on this page?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having this SAME issue myself.

Using `<applet code=""></applet>` doesn't work, but `<Applet>` or `<APPLET>` seems to work.

Google Chrome and IE.